# Best way to use MongoDB with Nextjs

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am wondering how I should handle setting up a connection to my MongoDB database in Nextjs. Previously I have learned to make a connection and close it every time I want to do something with my database but I found out that doing it that way is inefficient. What I have tried to do now is only create a connection if there isn't one and reuse the same db object from it but when looking at my database page, it usually shows that there are 10+ connections every time I visit a page that uses MongoDB. Here is what I have done:

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";

let db: Db;

class Mongo {
  client: MongoClient;
  constructor() {
    this.client = new MongoClient(
      'correct-url'
    );
  }

  async boot() {
    await this.client.connect();
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    db = this.client.db();
  }
}

const mongo = new Mongo();

const connectToMongo = async () => {
  if (!db) {
    await mongo.boot();
  }

  return db;
};

export default connectToMongo;
```

('correct-url') is a valid url.

I then use this in 'getServerSideProps'

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  context.res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, s-maxage=300, stale-while-revalidate=300"
  );
  const { slug } = context.query;
  let collection;
  try {
    const db = await connectToMongo();
    collection = (await db
      .collection("Collections")
      .findOne(
        { name: slug![0] },
        { projection: { _id: 0 } }
      ));

    console.log(collection);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  const found = collection ? true : false;
  return {
    props: { collection },
    notFound: !found,
  };
};
```

So I have a few questions:

1. What is the proper way to use MongoDB with Nextjs?
2. Do you ever have to close the client?
3. If this is hosted on vercel and say I have 10 people on the site at once, should there be 10 connections to the database or just 1?